# Is it possible to add a Laravel Elixir task from inside a package?

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

I'm building a Laravel 5 package, and I'd like to know if it is possible to add an Elixir test "automatically" (from inside the Service Provider) from my package. That way, after installing the package, the user could run "elixir task-from-my-package" without defining `task-from-my-package` at its gulpfile.